# Aggregate finished threads and send the response after timeout rX Java

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I have a use case where I need to aggregate the finished thread responses from multiple Observable objects and return back to the client. My question is how to achieve it with using the rX Java. Here I have written a code snippet but the issue of this one is that this won't return anything after the timeout.

```
Observable<AggregateResponse> aggregateResponse = Observable.
   zip(callServiceA(endpoint), callServiceB(endpoint), callServiceC(endpoint),
        (Mashup resultA, Mashup resultB, Mashup resultC) -> {
            AggregateResponse result = new AggregateResponse();
            result.setResult(resultA.getName() + " " + resultB.getName() + " " + resultC.getName());
            return result;
        }).timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Subscriber

```
aggregateResponse.subscribe(new Subscriber<AggregateResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            //Timeout execute this rather than aggregating the finished tasks
            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
            System.out.println(throwable.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(AggregateResponse response) {
            asyncResponse.resume(response);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `timeout` operator on each `Observable`, `zip` will wait for all Observables to emit a value before emitting a result, so if only one of them take longer while others already emitted, you will cut down the stream with the `timeout` (with `onError`) before the zipped Observable will have a chance to emit.

What you should do, assuming you want to ignore timed out sources while keeping the rest, is to add timeout operator to each `Observable` and also add error handling like `onErrorReturn` to each one, the error return can return some kind of 'empty' result (you can't use null in RxJava2), and when you aggregate result ignore those empty results:

```
Observable<AggregateResponse> aggregateResponse = Observable.
            zip(callServiceA(endpoint)
                            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new Mashup()),
                    callServiceB(endpoint)
                            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new Mashup()),
                    callServiceC(endpoint)
                            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new Mashup()),
                    (Mashup resultA, Mashup resultB, Mashup resultC) -> {
                        AggregateResponse result = new AggregateResponse();
                        result.setResult(resultA.getName() + " " + resultB.getName() + " " + resultC.getName());
                        return result;
                    });
```

Comment: Only issue I found with the solution is that it wait till the thread end execution. Eg. If the thread end execution after 30 seconds I am getting the response after 30+ seconds.

Comment: That's the behavior of zip, you can use combineLatest to get update for each emission immediately

Comment: Even combineLatest is behave in the same way.

Comment: maybe I didn't understand your question?

Comment: My question was that even after setting the timeout to 5 seconds, it won't return up until the callable finish the task. I am expecting to finish the tasks or return within 5 seconds.